# Is there any specific reason why the chr function won't accept a higher answer?

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, built-in, chr

Does anybody know if there is a specific reason why the `chr` function throws an error if I enter a number higher than 1114111?
EG:

```py
>>> chr(1114111)
'\U0010ffff'
>>> chr(1114112)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       chr(1114112)
>   ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there *is* a specific reason. It's because that's the highest code point in the Unicode code space. From the current standard (12.0), section `1.3 Text handling`, under `Text elements`:

> An encoded character is represented by a number from `0` to `10ffff16`, called a code point.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers need to be in a certain range in order to be valid, so no it won’t accept a number greater than or equal to 0x110000 because that is the smallest positive integer that is not in the unicode code space.